# Need to change the resolution options

Tags: 11.04, monitor, resolution

I've been trying to add my external monitor's native resolution (1680x1050). It does not show up on the GUI "Monitors"

I followed the "Adding Undetected Resolutions" section of
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution
Here is what I got:

```
chris@chris-laptop:~$ cvt 1680 1050
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync     +vsync
chris@chris-laptop:~$ xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240      1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
chris@chris-laptop:~$ xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050
xrandr: cannot find mode "1680x1050"
chris@chris-laptop:~$ xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050
xrandr: cannot find mode "1680x1050"
chris@chris-laptop:~$ xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00
chris@chris-laptop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1680x1050_60.00   60.0  
LVDS connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x800       60.0 +
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9
```

The example was as follows:

```
$ cvt 800 600
# 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600
```

I tried to use exactly what they had (replacing 800x600 with 1680x1050), but it didn't recognize 1680x1050 as a mode. So I tried 1680x1050_60.00 which didn't give me an error message, but also didn't add it to xranr.

Comment: Have you looked for the monitors edid online? you need correct sync data as well as the resolution. These used to be available in the ini files which would come with monitor install 'driver' programs. Now I'm not sure where you'd find them. I wonder why the edid isn't detected properly anyway. If you can, report your Xorg log file in your question so we can see what's detected.

Comment: Actually, the new mode was added, it's the las one for VGA-0.

Answer (score 4):

**The following worked for me trying to get my Acer AL2223W to work with kubuntu 12.04 LTS dual monitor**

In trying to execute:

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

I got the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
Serial number of failed request:  39
Current serial number in output stream:  39
```

So, I tried it after removing "_60.00" and received no error:

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

Then adding with no error:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050
```

And then was able to set my VGA1 output to 1680x1050 with no problem.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem -  Ubuntu not recognizing my second monitor higher resolutions. I solved it with a new VGA cable. I think there are two types 14 and 15 pins... Worth trying...